# android how to upload zip file using retrofit

Tags: java, android

```
    private void getAdharDetails() {
        try {
            if (common.isNetworkAvailable(EQLActivity.this)) {
                String sharecode=sharecodeEdt.getText().toString();
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                File file = new File(strPath);
                // Parsing any Media type file
                RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);
                MultipartBody.Part fileToUpload = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", file.getName(), requestBody);
                RequestBody filename = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), file.getName());

                APIService service = apiclient.getAdhaarDetails().create(APIService.class);
                Call<AadhaarDetails> call1 = service.uploadAdhar(fileToUpload ,filename,"zip_extract", sharecode);
                call1.enqueue(new Callback<AadhaarDetails>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<AadhaarDetails> call, Response<AadhaarDetails> response) {
                        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            firstLay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            secondLay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            continueBtn.setText("SUBMIT");
//                            AadhaarDetails.AddressInfo results = response.body().getData().getAddressInfo();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<AadhaarDetails> call, Throwable t) {
                        Log.d("TestTag", "exc: " + t);
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                });

            } else {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                common.showtoast("Unable to connect to the internet.", EQLActivity.this);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

//here is the retrofit service
 @POST("zip-extractor.php")
    @Multipart
    Call<AadhaarDetails> uploadAdhar(@Part MultipartBody.Part file,
                                     @Part("file") RequestBody name,
                                     @Part("op_type") String op_type,
                                     @Part("share_code") String share_code);
```

I am implementing retrofit in my android application and I am trying to upload a zip file but it is not working. I am getting `BEGIN OBJECT EXPECTED STRING` error in onFailure. When I try to upload the file in postman I am getting the response.

Comment: Add log interceptor and see what response you are getting exactly. Also make Sure `strPath` has the correct file path. Or maybe [follow this](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-upload-files-to-server).

Comment: Please check AadhaarDetails model/data class.It seems response and model/data is not matching with variable data type declare in class.